# not in function in spark sql java

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql

Is there any '*is not in*' and '*not like*' functions in **java spark sql**, I have to convert below query

```
CASE WHEN COL_1 = 'Y' AND COL_2 NOT IN ('A','B','C','D') AND COL_2 NOT Like 
    'NRV%' then 1 else 0
```

**org.apache.spark.sql.functions** supports *isin* and *like* functions, How to write *is not in* and *not like* using **java**?

```
functions.when(functions.col("COL_1").equalTo("Y")
.and(functions.col("COL_2").isin("A","B","C","D"))
.and(functions.col("COL_2").like("NRV%")), 1).otherwise(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a combination of `not` and `isin` :

```
functions.when(functions.col("COL_1").equalTo("Y")
.and(functions.not(functions.col("COL_2").isin("A","B","C","D")))
.and(functions.not(functions.col("COL_2").like("NRV%"))), 1).otherwise(0)
```

Comment: In Java, yes, there is no other way

Comment: any function to check less than or equal to as well? like gt and lt functions

Comment: Yep, `functions.col("COL").gt(otherValue)`

Comment: gt is to check 'greater than' or 'greater than or equal to'?

Comment: `gt` => "greater than" and `geq` => "greater or equal".
Generally, when you want to perform operations on columns, the two main classes you'll have to refer to are `Column` : https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html and `functions` : https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html